# Включаемый файл включает самого себя

Tags: c++

Есть три файла: `DllMain.h`, `Player.h` и `Chest.h`. У каждого из этих файлов есть так же .cpp где находится сам код. В заголовочных файлах только объявления и разные `#include`. Каждый из этих трёх файлов должен иметь доступ к вызовам OpenGL функций (GL.h) DllMain должен иметь возможность вызывать функции `draw()` из Player.h и Chest.h. А Player.h и Chest.h должны иметь возможность вызывать OpenGL функции. Если подключать GL.h ко всем трем файлам, то будет много разных ошибок. Если в Player.h и Chest.h написать `#include "DllMain.h"` в котором прописано `#include "GL.h"`, то нужно ещё подключить Player.h и Chest.h в DllMain.h иначе я из DllMain.h не буду иметь возможность вызывать `draw()` в Player.h и Chest.h. И тут появляется ошибка когда файл включает самого себя. Как решить эту проблему более правильно?

Comment: Используйте "include guard"

Comment: Мне кажется, я не столкнулся бы с подобной проблемой, если бы понимал, как правильно проектировать проект. Можно ли где-то на понятном языке об этом почитать? Или я всё же не прав и при правильном проектировании с таким тоже сталкиваются?

Comment: Player.h и Chest.h точно не должны включать в себя DllMain.h; Не совсем понятно какие ошибки и при включении GL.h, но подозреваю что у вас в один cpp файл два раза попадает одни и тот же заголовочный. Добавьте в начало каждого вашего заголовочного файла `pragma once`  или вставляете ваш код в заголовочный файлах между `#if defined PLAYER_H   #define PLAYER_H    #endif`

Comment: #pragma once помогло, но я думаю что я не правильно изначально что-то спроектировал. Напишите это как ответ и я его приму.

Comment: Вместо мутного словесного описания следует приводить [mcve]. А вообще в каждый файл следует включать все заголовочные файлы, символы из которых тот использует, т.е. делать каждый файл самодостаточным.

Comment: Всё очень просто весь код занесите в `.cpp` файлы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У С++ одна из основных проблем это хедеры.

Хедеры это такой хак, чтобы можно было писать большие программы, несмотря на то что рефлексии и рантайма нет. Всё что делает препроцессор на #include , это вставляет содержимое файла вместо этой строки, и НИЧЕГО кроме этого.

Пускай есть 4 файла

a.h

```
int a(int l);
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h" 
#include "b.h" 
int a(int l){
    if(l<=0) return 1;
    return b(l-1)+2;
}
```

b.h

```
int b(int l);
```

b.cpp

```
#include "a.h" 
#include "b.h" 
int b(int l){
    if(l<=0) return 1;
    return a(l-1)*3;
}
```

Фактически компилятору серавно что в хедерах, пока он не встретит инклуд, он их будет игнорировать. И для него эти файлы будут выглядеть так:

a_complie_unit

```
int a(int l);
int b(int l);
int a(int l){
    if(l<=0) return 1;
    return b(l-1)+2;
}
```

b_complie_unit

```
int a(int l);
int b(int l);
int b(int l){
    if(l<=0) return 1;
    return a(l-1)*3;
}
```

Так как объявление классов можно делать только 1 раз, и чтобы не вставлять 100 одинаковых копий текста, во всех компилчторах есть второй хак:

```
#pragma once
```

всё что он делает, это запрещает второй раз включать этот файл.

Теперь что касается 3 файлов друг на друга:
Включать хедер в хедере нужно если:

1. нужны объявления клссов/структур
2. или нужны функции из хедеров для темплейтовых или инлайновых функций(для обычных функций вллючать хедер надо в .cpp а не в .h)

Также стоит учесть что для передачи аргументов и возврата по ссылке, а также возвращаемого значения функций достаточно форвард декларации.

И если есть 3 хедера включающих друг друга значит это реально где-то проблема, не должно быть циклического инклуда, прагма онц тут только скроет проблему, но не решит её, она вернётся потом.

> Если подключать GL.h ко всем трем файлам, то будет много разных ошибок.

Счегобы? Я всегда так делал. https://gitlab.com/nikitasamoukov/irambis/-/blob/master/irambis/src/pch.h
Подключил GLAD ко всем файлам .cpp через предкомпилированный заголовок и всё.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
```

Comment: Попробуйте подключить GL.h без предкомпилированного заголовка и #pragma once, будет куча ошибок (Его надо подключать в .h файле или .cpp? Я всегда думал что #include нужно прописывать в .h файле а не .cpp. Где можно об этом прочитать?)

Comment: прагма онц надо добавлять в хедер всегда, иначе будет включено несколько определений одного класса/фунцции и ничего не скомпилится, к счастью об этом почти все создатели либ знают и ставят его в хедеры. glad это загрузчик указателей функций из драйвера, он сам по себе не генерит ерроры. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library если же gl.h ведёт себя иначе, то стоит перейти на более рабочий glad. А про хедеры C++ прямо не пишут, кому надо и так знают, а остальные не поймут. https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/344534/  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию в cpp-файл два раза попадает один и тот же заголовочный файл, например:

```
 DllMain.cpp <- Chest.h <- Player.h
             <- Player.h
```

То еcть в логике `DllMain` необходимо работать с двумя сущностями: `Player` и `Chest`. В свою очередь сущности `Chest` нужен `Player`.

DllMain.cpp:

```
 #include "Chest.h"
 #include "Player.h"
 ...
```

Chest.h:

```
  #include "Player.h"
```

Chest.cpp:

```
  #include "Chest.h"
```

Это вполне адекватная ситуация, нюанс в том что компилятор при обработке `#include` вставляет все содержимое файла, в итоге получаем ошибки множественного определения. Чтобы это исправить нужно в начале каждого заголовочного файла писать `#pragma once`, либо:

Chest.h:

```
 #if defined CHEST_H
 #define CHEST_H
 ...
 #endif
```